# How to average every nth column while excluding blanks (not zeros) in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

I'm trying to average every 4th column in a row of test scores (the percentages) though sometimes these may include blanks if a student doesn't take this test. My current method works at averaging the percentages but breaks down when there is a blank.

My method:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(K7:ZZ7),4)=2)*K7:ZZ7))/SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(K7:ZZ7),4)=2)*(K7:ZZ7<>""))
```

How can I exclude it from counting the blanks?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank yous are appreciated, but not useful. If it is the answer, then you mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With Excel 365 you can do:

```
=AVERAGE( INDEX( K7:ZZ7,,SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(K:ZZ)/4,4,4)) )
```

If you don't have Excel 365, just say so and there is a method available for prior versions that is a little longer, but delivers the same results.

Comment: THANK YOU! it all works now, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Great! So, is it the answer? If so, please mark it as the answer.